Vulnerability reported in the dependent package "micromatch" when I installed Tailwind css
When I was trying instal Tailwind on my vite react project with this command
> npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
I see this report
3 moderate vulnerabilities: added 92 packages, and audited 308 packages in 9s

125 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run: npm audit fix

Run npm audit for details.


I run npm audit fix and I see this bug error
up to date, audited 308 packages in 2s

125 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details

npm audit report
micromatch * Severity: moderate Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in micromatch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-952p-6rrq-rcjv fix available via npm audit fix --force Will install tailwindcss@3.2.0, which is a breaking change node_modules/micromatch fast-glob * Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch node_modules/fast-glob tailwindcss <=0.0.0-oxide-insiders.ff2c25f || 2.1.0-canary.1 - 3.4.10 Depends on vulnerable versions of fast-glob Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch node_modules/tailwindcss

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: npm audit fix --force 

I was trying run this command npm audit fix --force and doenst work
I want to fix this Vulnerability

seems to be a developing issue - https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/14233 - there is a merge request waiting it looks like

do npm i micromatch@4.0.8 worked for me
